# How to increase iterrows operations speed in pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a data frame which contains thousands of entries which contain the regression results on different variable combinations. The combinations for the regression are formed using a list of single variables and the itertools combinations functions.

I am now looking at a way to remove variable combinations that need to be removed as they represent similar measures. I have made a list of all the variables that cannot occur together. My code iterates over the data frame containing the combinations and uses the `collections.Counter` function to count the number of elements within each row that is within the duplicate list. If two of more of the elements are within the row, then the row is not copied to a new cleaned data frame. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import random
from collections import Counter

def remove_elements(data, dup_col, duplicate_list):
    """
    Removes items from a dataframe that contain multiple items from the duplicate list.

    Arguments:
        data (dataframe): Dataframe containing the data
        dup_col (string): Column name for within data to check for duplicates
        duplicate_list (list): List of duplicate items

    Returns:
        cleaned dataframe
    """
    df_cleaned = pd.DataFrame()
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if any(ele in  duplicate_list for ele in row[dup_col]):
            lenduplicate = sum(Counter(set.intersection(set(duplicate_list), set(row[dup_col]))).values())
            if lenduplicate > 1:
                continue
            else:
                df_cleaned = df_cleaned.append(row)
        else:
            df_cleaned = df_cleaned.append(row)

    return df_cleaned

#%% Create Data

df = pd.DataFrame()
models = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
df['model'] = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(models, 4)]
df['result'] = [random.randint(1,101) for i in range(0,len(df['model']))]


# Run Function
same_elements = ['A', 'D', 'G'] 
df = remove_elements(df, 'model', same_elements)
```

The function seems to work okay, but on a data frame which contains thousands of entries is it taking 20 to 30 minuets.  Is it possible to make this operation faster?

Any advice welcome.

BJR

Comment: can you post an example of input and output of the dataset?

Comment: There is code to create an example data set 'Under create data', or are you asking for a visual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `np.intersect1d` to create a mask where the length of that intersection is two or more and boolean flip it to only retain desired elements from your original dataframe.

```
df[~df.model.apply(lambda L: len(np.intersect1d(L, same_elements)) >= 2)]
```

Which'll give you identical output as per your existing code:

```
           model  result
1   [A, B, C, E]      39
2   [A, B, C, F]      62
7   [A, B, E, F]      10
13  [A, C, E, F]      28
20  [B, C, D, E]      38
21  [B, C, D, F]      33
24  [B, C, E, G]       9
25  [B, C, F, G]      11
26  [B, D, E, F]      73
29  [B, E, F, G]       1
30  [C, D, E, F]      96
33  [C, E, F, G]      77
```

Comment: That works like a charm, with a run time in the order of seconds. Thanks.